# How to project black lines in one image onto a shapefile?

Tags: qgis

[image]

I made my shapefile transparent and started drawing lines on the top of it using base map. It will take lot of time to do the same for all coloured palettes.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create an outline from the raster image, you will need to use the following steps:

1. Convert raster to vector using Polygonize (Raster to vector) tool
   accessed from `Processing toolbox -> [GDAL] Conversion -> Polygonize
   (Raster to vector)`
2. Start editing the output vector file
3. Add a new field of type integer, give it a name, assign all polygons
   with a value of zero, and save and stop editing
4. Use the dissolve tool, select the newly created field in step 3, and give a new name to the output vector file.

This should create a new outline vector file from the raster image. However, if you want to create polygons for each color, then you can follow the above process up to step 2.